# Assiging a specific data-type for temporary variable in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, integer, sqldatatypes

I have a query and I need to use the result of the query in other query. So, I used "WITH .. As". The problem is that the temporary variable should be integer while it was created in text data-type automatically.
How I can change or modify the code to have variable in integer data type.

```
WITH A as (
SELECT ambtemp,
       date_trunc('hour', dt)+
       CASE WHEN date_part('minute', dt) >= 30
            THEN interval '30 minutes'
            ELSE interval '0 minutes'
       END as t
FROM temm),

B as(
SELECT ambtemp,t,

       max(ambtemp) OVER (PARTITION BY t) as max_temp,
       min(ambtemp) OVER (PARTITION BY t) as min_temp
FROM A)
SELECT *

FROM B
WHERE (max_temp - min_temp) <= 0.2
```

max_temp and min_temp should be built in integer data-type while they are in text format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change types you need to cast them using the `::` operator. So to convert an integer into a string you would do `myCol::Text`.

In your specific case you are doing the reverse:

```
 max(ambtemp) OVER (PARTITION BY t) as max_temp::int,
 min(ambtemp) OVER (PARTITION BY t) as min_temp::int
```

You may want to check for nulls via:

```
NULLIF(your_value, '')::int
```

I would also be cautious of values that are not convertible to an integer.

See [The PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-expressions.html) for more info on casts and types.

Comment: Maybe `max(ambtemp::int) OVER (PARTITION BY t) as max_temp` ? `max(text)::int` and `max(text::int)` Can produce different results.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks, @Igor Romanchenko

```
WITH A as (
SELECT ambtemp,
       date_trunc('hour', dt)+
       CASE WHEN date_part('minute', dt) >= 30
            THEN interval '30 minutes'
            ELSE interval '0 minutes'
       END as t
FROM temm),

B as(
SELECT ambtemp,t,

       max(ambtemp::float(23)) OVER (PARTITION BY t) as max_temp,
       min(ambtemp::float(23)) OVER (PARTITION BY t) as min_temp
FROM A)
SELECT *

FROM B
WHERE (max_temp - min_temp) <= 0.2
```